# How to implement a weak_ptr getter?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, getter-setter, weak-ptr

I have a class (called Node) with a `weak_ptr` to an object that it doesn't own (called Level).

When implementing a getter for this pointer, should I just return the `weak_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` instead? One might argue that whether a class is using `weak_ptr` or not shouldn't concern the user of that class. And if I want to use the object in any way, I have to `lock()` it anyway, right? So I might as well just do that in the getter. Are there any problems with this?

```
class Node {
    std::weak_ptr<Level> _level;
public:
    const std::shared_ptr<Level> level() const { return _level.lock(); }
}

// somewhere else:

std::shared_ptr<Node> myNode;
// ...
auto level = myNode->level();
if (level) {
    // do stuff with level
}
```

Comment: Have you considered returning a const reference to the `weak_ptr`?

Comment: @pmdj I'm considering all options. I'm still trying to figure out the conventions when using smart pointers. Would you return a const ref to a `weak_ptr` and `lock()` it whenever/wherever you are accessing it?

Comment: I would have done the same thing as you did. Maybe codereview is a better place to ask this kind of question?

Comment: @AA Yes, myNode would be a shared_ptr.

Comment: Why do you return a `const` shared_ptr? It seems all it does is prevent move semantics. Did you mean `std::shared_ptr<const Level>`?

Comment: if Node cannot guarantee more than a weak reference, then returning a weak_ptr<>const& is equivalent, more performant and self-documenting. The user would just write *if( auto level = node.level().lock() )...*

Comment: @Jawap It's certainly more efficient than returning a `shared_ptr` with copy semantics. Move semantics would be essentially equivalent, assuming all clients of the API want a shared_ptr.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Honestly, because that's what my IDE generated :-S

Comment: The only problem I see is if you decide you want a caller to only have a `weak_ptr`. Then you will be locking it unnecessarily which would be a performance drain.